# org-mode, how to automatically generate nice file hierarchy trees with well-formed Org links

Tags: emacs, sh, org-mode

When working with Org-Mode, I am looking for a solution to automatically generate tree of well-formed org-mode links.

For instance, to create links to all c++ files under a directory, I want something like:

[image]

---

**Update:** I just tried @DamianChrzanowski suggestion, the [org-fstree](https://github.com/emacsmirror/org-fstree) package. However I am a little bit disappointed by the results:

[image]

The html export result is even worst:

[image]

My conclusion is that package does not fulfil my needs. Anyway, thanks to  @DamianChrzanowski for his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the [linux tree command](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/tree.htm) installed I came with the following script that fulfils all my needs:

```
#+NAME: createTree
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results drawer :var toInclude="*.org" :var toExclude="" :var directory="./" :var createLink="true" :exports none
set -e
buffer=$(mktemp /tmp/buffer.XXXXXXXXX)
current_directory=$(pwd)
cd $(eval echo "$directory")
tree -a -P "$toInclude" -I "$toExclude" -if --noreport  --prune \
    | sed "s/.//"  | sed "s/^\///"  > "$buffer"

if [ $(grep --regexp="$" --count "$buffer") -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "**ERROR empty list**"
else
    for f in $(cat "$buffer")
    do 
    filename=$(basename $f)
    ext="${filename##*.}"
    baseFilename="${filename%.*}"
    if [ -f $f ]; then
        # removes org extension (only)
        if [ "$ext" = "org" ]; then
        filename="$baseFilename"
        fi
        # creates org link (or not)
        if [ "$createLink" = true ]; then 
        echo "$(echo "$f" | tr -cd / | tr / \\t)+ [[file:"$directory/$f"][$filename]]"
        else
        echo "$(echo "$f" | tr -cd / | tr / \\t)+ $filename"
        fi
    else
        echo  "$(echo "$f" | tr -cd / | tr / \\t)+ $filename/"
    fi
    done
fi
rm "$buffer"
cd "$current_directory"
#+END_SRC
```

If you want to create a file tree of your C++ code, simply use something like:

```
#+CALL: createTree(toInclude="*.[hc]pp",toExclude="*test*",directory="~/MyProject")
```

Also, note that you can use it as an alternative to sitemap when you export/publish your org-mode documents. Simply use:

```
* My site content

#+CALL: createTree(toInclude="*.org",toExclude="Setup")
```

The previous `#+CALL` commands will generate tree like the one I posted in my question. After Org HTML export, you will get something like:
[image]

---

The command arguments/options are:

- **toInclude="..."** : pattern to include
- **toExclude="..."** : pattern to exclude
- **directory="..."** : directory
- **createLink="true" or "false"** : if false the tree is created without links

---

**Note 1:** you can store the script in any .org file and load it thanks to [Library-of-Babel](http://orgmode.org/manual/Library-of-Babel.html) :

In your `init.el` file:

```
(org-babel-lob-ingest "~/path/to/your/scripts.org")
```

---

**Note 2:** I answered my own question, but I am still open to a pure Emacs-Lisp solution.

Answer (score 1):

There usually is a package :-)
[org-fstree](https://melpa.org/#/org-fstree)

Comment: wow, I was not aware of it... I will have a look. Thanks for the link.

Comment: No problem! I hope it does the job

Comment: I just tested the package, however, I am a little bit disappointed by the result (see my post update). I still prefer my solution :)

Comment: Oh. I'm a little bit disappointed myself. But I think that you want recursion, so go with non-recursion nil. It sounds counter intuitive I know :-( you also might want relative links. I'll test this myself once I'll finish studying for the exam.

Comment: I just ran it there with just the directory path and no extra parameters. It works just fine. The only problem is with the exported html and files that have square brackets and underscores. So the package definitely needs fine tuning. Sorry for not being too helpful!

Comment: No problem! Thanks for your answer, we learned some stuff, that is the important thing!

Answer (score 1):

I just tried [org-fs-tree](https://github.com/ScriptDevil/org-fs-tree) and it seems to do the job well. It's a newer package, looks like `org-fstree` is orphaned.